# Can I spy a class?

Tags: ruby, rspec

In the effort to make more readable my test suite, I'm introducing spies in my specs but I'm not sure how to deal with class methods. Is it possible to "spy a class"?

Let's say I have the following sample code

```
  def publish(post)
    Publisher.call(post)
    post.save
  end
```

And the correspondent spec

```
it 'delegates the publishing to Publisher' do
  let(:blog) { ... }
  let(:post) { ... }

  expect(Publisher).to receive(:call).with(post).and_call_original
  blog.publish(post)
end
```

Is it possible to rewrite the spec using a spy?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use [spies on partial doubles](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/spies#spy-on-a-method-on-a-partial-double) via `allow` plus `expect`:

```
it 'delegates the publishing to Publisher' do
  let(:blog) { ... }
  let(:post) { ... }

  allow(Publisher).to receive(:call)
  blog.publish(post)
  expect(Publisher).to have_received(:call).with(post)
end
```

Comment: @macsig haven't tried it, but you probably have to `allow(Publisher).to receive(:call).and_call_original`